# How to test builder with Mockito - Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a builder class written in Java that I would like to test with Mockito.

**Profile.java**

```
@Data
@Document
public class Profile {

    public final String birthDate;
    public final City city;
    public final Country country;
    public final String imageId;
    public final Team team;

    public Profile(String birthDate,
                   City city,
                   Country country,
                   String imageId,
                   Team team) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.team = team;
    }

    public static ProfileBuilder builder() {
        return new ProfileBuilder();
    }

    public static final class ProfileBuilder {
        public String birthDate;
        public City city;
        public Country country;
        public String imageId;
        public Team team;

        public ProfileBuilder() {
        }

        public ProfileBuilder withBirthDate(String birthDate) {
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
            return this;
        }

        public ProfileBuilder withCity(City city) {
            this.city = city;
            return this;
        }

        public ProfileBuilder withCountry(Country country) {
            this.country = country;
            return this;
        }

        public ProfileBuilder withImageId(String imageId) {
            this.imageId = imageId;
            return this;
        }

        public ProfileBuilder withTeam(Team team) {
            this.team = team;
            return this;
        }

        public Profile build(){
            return new Profile(birthDate, city, country, imageId, team);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this method to add Profile to database

```
@Override
    public Profile addProfile(Profile profile) {

        Profile createdProfile = Profile.builder()
                .withBirthDate(profile.getBirthDate())
                .withCity(profile.getCity())
                .withCountry(profile.getCountry())
                .withTeam(profile.getTeam())
                .withImageId(profile.getImageId())
                .build();

        return profileRepository.save(createdProfile);
    }
```

I am trying to test it like this:

```
public class ProfileServiceImplTest {

    ProfileRepository profileRepository = Mockito.mock(ProfileRepository.class);
    private final ProfileServiceImpl profileService = new ProfileServiceImpl(profileRepository);

    City city = Mockito.mock(City.class);
    Country country = Mockito.mock(Country.class);
    Team team = Mockito.mock(Team.class);

    @Test
    public void addProfileTest(){

        Profile profile = new Profile("25.07.1996", city, country, "imageId", team);

        Profile.ProfileBuilder profileBuilderMock = Mockito.mock(Profile.ProfileBuilder.class);

        when(profileBuilderMock.build()).thenReturn(profile);

        verify(profileRepository, times(1)).save(profile);
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
profileRepository.save(
    Profile(birthDate=25.07.1996, city=Mock for City, hashCode: 997294994, country=Mock for Country, hashCode: 506775047, imageId=imageId, team=Mock for Team, hashCode: 451959555)
);
-> at com.profile.profileservice.service.ProfileServiceImplTest.addProfileTest(ProfileServiceImplTest.java:31)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You never actually call `addProfile()` in your test (neither explicitly nor implicitly).

Comment: Yes, that is true I was so focused on testing builder :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are not calling `addProfile()` in your test. Also, you don't need to mock the `ProfileBuilder` here as `Profile.builder()` returns a new instance. It will not return the mocked instance.

Tip : use the [*given/when/then*](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/gwt/#q=%7E(infinite%7Efalse%7Efilters%7E(postType%7E(%7E%27page%7E%27post%7E%27aa_book%7E%27aa_event_session%7E%27aa_experience_report%7E%27aa_glossary%7E%27aa_research_paper%7E%27aa_video)%7Etags%7E(%7E%27given*20when*20then))%7EsearchTerm%7E%27%7Esort%7Efalse%7EsortDirection%7E%27asc%7Epage%7E1)) pattern for writing tests. This will help to not forget this kind of things.

```java
@Test
void addProfileTest(){
   // Given
   Profile profile = new Profile("25.07.1996", city, country, "imageId", team);

   // When
   profileService.addProfile(profile);

   // Then
   verify(profileRepository, times(1)).save(profile);
}
```

This test passes.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me realise how to do it